# Jmeter compatiblity for java based ERP application

Tags: jmeter

We need to perform load testing on Java based ERP application, and we're thinking about using JMeter. Is it possible to test more than one screen at time, since output of first screen is the input for second screen, kindly assist us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate user navigation, I believe you should record two, or more, different navigation scenarios, and then simply run them in parallel. For instructions on how to record a navigation, read [this document](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).
On the other hand, if what you meant is to use the result of a request as input to a subsequent one, have a look [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/can-I-use-a-test-result-as-an-input-in-another-test-td3214281.html).